# Parameterized SQL, ORACLE vs SQL Server with regular expression

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, oracle

Oracle and Sql server using different prefix for parameters in parametrized string.

Sql using `@p1`

ORA using `:p1`

I would like to use in my SQL just `@` and in case that ORA database is used all `:` character should be replaces with `@`.

Can you please help me to create regular expression?

Here is some example SQL:

`update test_table set text = :p1 where text = 'jana:klara' or some_value = :value or info = 'two'`

Similar question and alternative solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295699/dbcommand-and-parameterized-sql-oracle-vs-sql-server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct regex:

```
 statement = Regex.Replace(statement, @":(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'\n])*$)", "@");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern for your search search:

```
(?<=\W):(?=\w+)
```

For instance:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\W):(?=\w+)", "@");
```

Here's the meaning of the pattern:

- `(?<=\W)` - The `(?<= ... )` syntax declares a positive look-behind.  In other words, any match must be preceded by the contents of the look-behind.  In this case, it's declaring that matches must be preceded by a non-word character.
- `:` - Matches just the colon
- `(?=\w+)` - The `(?= ... )` syntax declares a positive look-ahead.  In other words, any match must be followed by the contents of the look-ahead.  In this case, it's declaring that matches must be followed by a one or more word-characters.

See the [online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CW)%3A(%3F%3D%5Cw%2B)&i=update%20test_table%20set%20text%20%3D%20%3Ap1%20where%20text%20%3D%20%27jana%3Aklara%27%20or%20some_value%20%3D%20%3Avalue%20or%20info%20%3D%20%27two%27%0D%0A%0D%0Aupdate%20test_table%20set%20text%20%3D%3Ap1%20where%20text%20%3D%20%27jana%3Aklara%27%20or%20some_value%20%3D%3Avalue%20or%20info%20%3D%20%27two%27&r=%40).

I can't think of any reason why the parameter would be the first thing in the input string, but if that were possible, changing it to `(?<=^|\W):(?=\w+)` would take care of that situation too.

Comment: I found that replacement for this UPDATE B_BSET SET VALUE_DATE = '14.07.2011' WHERE BATCH_NAME = ':BWAG_ALM2' not working correctly.  :BWAG_ALM2  is changed to  @BWAG_ALM2. Any idea?

Comment: What about this `:(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'\n])*$)` ? I think that this is working correctly.